# JPA query to search only by date by ignoring time

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entity

I need help to write the JPA query (or function) to remove timestamps in search queries.

I am using MySQL DB.
My table consist of create_date(datetime) column.
My entity mapped with create_date using LocalDateTime

@Column(name = "create_date")
private LocalDateTime createDate;

I can achieve using the Mysql query in two ways.

1. select * from table_name where DATE(create_date) between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'
2. select * from table_name where create_date between '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and '2019-07-31 23:59:59'.

I can achieve results using JPA also bypassing timestamp like
"where createDate between '2019-07-01 00:00:00' and '2019-07-31 23:59:59'"

Is there a way to build a query without passing time?
Something similar to Mysql query No.1

Answer (score 0):

OHHHHHH I found an answer.

where DATE(createDate) between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31' is working.